# How to target a string containing unknown random characters?

Tags: php, replace, find

I have a meta tag which includes a random string of numbers and a colon. The meta tag will be removed on each page but the random string makes it impossible to target as a key.

`<meta name="meta-id" content="14132c273f72a2:12b3a1fc6b46dc" />`

Each page will have the same number of random numbers prepended and appended to the colon.

**How can I target this meta tag when there are random content strings loaded with each page?**

Comment: Just grab the `<meta>` tag with `name="meta-id"`?

Comment: Bingo... `$tags = get_meta_tags($readfile); $meta_id_tag = $tags['the-meta-id'];$meta_id =  '<meta name="btwebnetwork-meta-id" content="meta-id" />';$find_replace = [$meta_id_tag => 'meta-id',$meta_id    =>  'foo',]` written into the rest of my code did the trick!!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use a simple regular expression that matches your tag:

```
preg_match('/<meta name="meta-id" content=".*" \/>/', $html, $matches);
```

After calling this, `$matches[0]` will contain the  meta tag. If you need to store the random string, you can use:

```
preg_match('/<meta name="meta-id" content="(.*)" \/>/', $html, $matches);
```

Then `$matches[0]` will store the full meta tag, and `$matches[1]` will contain the random string.

I noticed that your question is tagged [replace](/questions/tagged/replace), so I'll add a variation that replaces the meta tag with an empty string:

```
preg_replace('/<meta name="meta-id" content=".*" \/>/', '', $html);
```